# What is the significance of the imaginary parts in the output of an Inverse Fourier Transform? Can I avoid them?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform

Starting with an image, I have taken its fourier transform and then modified it, and finally taken the inverse fourier transform of the modified fourier transform to get my resulting image.  In my result, I get a lot of very small imaginary components in each pixel.  My question is what causes these, and is there some insight into how I can play with a fourier transform in such a way that I won't get these imaginary components once I invert the transform at the end?

The reason this is an issue for me is because although I can simply zero out the imaginary components, or take the magnitude of each complex number as the pixel value and still obtain the resulting image that I desire, once I take the fourier transform of that new image, it does not yield the fourier transform that I used to generate the image previously.  Because the English is getting messy, it's much easier to see in pseudocode:

```
function fft(input):
   return 2D fourier transform of input 2D array

function ifft(input):
   return 2D inverse fourier transform of input 2D array

function fix(image):
   zero out imaginary component in each pixel of input image (2D array)
   return updated image

// Suppose we have computed an input 2D matrix, and are ready to ifft it to get an image
input = /*...*/
test1 = fft(ifft(input))
test2 = fft(fix(ifft(input)))
```

While `test1` will yield back the matrix (up to floating point errors) `input` that we started with, the image generated is not a real image.  If we attempt to `fix` the image, we find that `test2` significantly differs from our `input`.

What I would like to do is understand how to modify the fourier transform in such a way that I can achieve my original input after going through the process of taking the inverse fourier transform, storing that as a valid image, and then taking the fourier transform of that image.

Comment: You are seeing the effect of rounding errors. Try to compute the Fourier transform with better precision.

Comment: If you want a transform which has strictly real output, you can use [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) instead of DFT.

Comment: No, this is not the effect of rounding errors.  If I take my input image, apply fft then ifft then clip off all imaginary components, then ifft, I get a result that is very close to the output of just applying fft to the original image.  The fourier transform maps complex numbers to complex numbers, it's not an error if our output yields complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier Transform is the change of basis, the discrete signal from image, which is finite, gets transformed into sines. The transformation itself is prone to rounding, because in frequency domain there is no such thing as finite impulse or rectangular for that matter (see Gibbs effect), there will be some approximation.

The complex numbers represent the transformed signal, where amplitude is the length (magnitude) of the number while phase is the angle. Cutting off the imaginary part destroys the phase and changes the amplitude so image looks like a noise. There is no way to avoid Imaginary part (unless the image itself is fully even-symmetric then Im is zero).

The small components in Imaginary part cannot be avoided, extending precision will help a lot, but please keep in mind that some inputs cannot be preserved and some loss will occur. Using only magnitude and discarding the phase is equivalent to saving pixel intensities and discarding the location.

If you want to store FFT result as the valid image, the best idea is to produce two images, for Real and Imaginary part or another pair using Phase and Magnitude. Another idea is to save separate channels, which works for grayscale image but is not sn option for grayscale. This operation is very lossy, some fixed unsigned integer (for example 8bit) is converted into complex pair, both floating point, so using any standard storage option will lose crucial data. Probably to make it work the log transform would be need.

Comment: I don't think you've read the question carefully, please reread.  Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: My question: "What is the significance of the imaginary parts in the output of an Inverse Fourier Transform?"  Your answer: talking about imaginary parts of the Fourier Transform.

Comment: The significance of the question is:  let `test1 = fft(image); test2 = fft(real_part(ifft(test1)))`.  If I now compare `test1` and `test2`, they are very close (e.g. by using an L2 norm).  If, on the other hand, I created `test1` (e.g. by applying a filter in the fourier domain to the fft of an image), and then performed this same test as above, I will find that `test2` is very far from `test1` (and that the imaginary parts of the ifft of `test1` are orders of magnitude larger than they were in the previous case).  The goal is to understand how to avoid this.

Comment: It's not a lucky test, it's just math.  Anyway, I'll probably post in the Signal Processing site, this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: That's ridiculous, the fft of any image avoids it.  You may not know how to avoid it; that does not make it unavoidable.

Comment: Sorry, but your title, body and expectations (from comments) do not match. If you insist on destroying part of your image in the frequency domain, please do not behave like that, implying that someone knows nothing about it. I find it impolite. Anyway, your goal is different than question states, please clarify it. What you describe is wrong way to handle images, so finding a workaround will not work.

Comment: Nope, your (continued) poor understanding of English is neither my fault nor my problem.

Comment: Apparently there are more important things to you than answer. When you change your mind, use edit, otherwise it is futile.